# can i use -crf and -s option in one command with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to create video streaming for phone. To do that i use ffmpeg to convert video into hls. For now i can convert video to hls using this command:

> ffmpeg -y  -i video.mp4 -profile:v
>   baseline -level 3.0 -crf 51 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10
>   -hls_list_size 0 -f hls video.m3u8.

I know i can reduce video image size by using this command:

> ffmpeg -y  -i video.mp4 -profile:v
>   baseline -level 3.0 -s 640x360 -r 20 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10
>   -hls_list_size 0 -f hls video.m3u8

can i use both -s and -crf in one command? 
Because i'm streaming for phone. so size is my main concern.

Comment: Yes. Did you get an error when you attempted it?

Comment: no. i just want to ensure it won't be have any conflict when using both these parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, crf stands for constant rate factor which is unrelated to the dimensions of your output. Generally speaking you’ll also get a conversion failed in your console when passing invalid flags.